# Why would Puppet version upgrade automatically?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I had puppet and now the version upgraded automatically. I thought it has to be done manually. Plus I have three different versions in my master(4.2.2) and other hosts under the same environment.
What would cause this to happen?

Comment: Could you add a bit more details to your issue? Do you mean that the puppet server was updated to a new major release? Or a new minor? Or a new patch?  
Also, what do you mean by three different versions?

Comment: I have one version of master, and the hosts have two different version, some with one and some with the other. I hope it clear things up. It is whatever you get with puppet --version command in Linux.

Comment: Check if any of your puppet manifest/hiera data/ENC, to check if updates to packages are automated, either through the package manager (yum/apt) or directly on the package (`ensure => latest`). Check also how you are installing puppet. We are installing it directly from the official repositories published by puppetlabs. That way we can ensure that all of our servers have the same version.

Comment: puppet enterprise wouldn't automatically update in general. you need to re-evaluate your puppet infrastructure. puppet enterprise isn't tied to a yum repo. the install is done using packages supplied in a tarball. sounds to me like there may have been manual upgrades to the master and other agent nodes never were upgraded (manual process). Also. what does three different versions in your master mean?

Comment: I said three different versions, including the master and hosts. And no it's an open source Puppet not enterprise. I think it has to do with (ensure => latest), as T0xic Code mentioned earlier.